# Adding onclick handler using jQuery attr method does not work in IE

Tags: jquery

Following code works fine in Firefox. In IE(8.0) button "2" does not work.

```
$('<button type="button" onclick="alert(1)">1</button>').appendTo($('body'));
$('<button type="button" >2</button>').attr('onclick','alert(2)').appendTo($('body'));
```

**Question:** what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should attach `click` handlers with [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead, like this:

```
$('<button type="button">2</button>').click(function() { alert(2); }).appendTo($('body'));
```

This is a shortcut for [`.bind('click', func)`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), though which you can bind any event, [several such shortcuts are available](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).